# Sending HTTP responses to web browser using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, http

I'm trying to make a simple web proxy using Python which prints to stdout HTTP requests and responses. Everything's quite fine, but sending the HTTP response to the browser doesn't work (the browser just keeps "spinning" :| ).

This is the code for that part:

```
bclient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
bclient.connect((self.browser_host, self.browser_port)) 
bclient.send(response)
bclient.close()
```

A sample response being sent is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Jun 2014 20:35:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dc09f975147aa6011cac3177c1646625; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 263
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Python.com</title>    
</head>

<frameset rows="100%,*" frameborder=0 border=0>
<frame name="main" src="inside.phtml?source=home&" frameborder="0">
</frameset>
</html>
```

I've tried adding a Connection: close header to the response, but with no results.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You mention a browser talking to a proxy, but a proxy is a server, and the Python code is for another client, not a server.

Comment: Oh dear, I've just realized I've added an extra client instead of simply coding server_socket.send(response).
Insomnia truly is evil.